# Name of a cheese they prepare in Switzerland

Tags: cheese

When I was in Switzerland, the cooks prepared a special Swiss type of cheese and I've been wondering how this was called. It looks a bit like doner kebab(in the sense it is on a stick and they used some flame on it) and it smells a lot. Just in case this helps - this was in Zurich(the meal may be local for there).

Can anyone help me in pointing the name of that cheese(or maybe the meal name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I ignore the "on a spit" part I immediately think of [Raclette](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raclette), which is melted, roasted cheese served typically with bread or boiled potato.

- In household settings the cheese is often heated in small individual pans under a table-top broiler, each guest gets his or her own pan and prepares his food.
- Traditionally (and in larger settings) halved wheels of cheese are turned with the cut side towards a heat source and servings of molten cheese scratched off. The heating can be done either at a fireplace (embers) or on a special "machine" consisting of a heat source and a (often movable) tray for the cheese(s). The melting and serving is done by one [cook](http://www.hotelchatter.com/story/2011/1/28/15446/2441/hotels/The_Beverly_Wilshire's_Raclette_Nights_Will_Make_You_Melt) for all participants. In Switzerland, but also sometimes in neighbourung countries, traditional Raclette is sold on food fairs, [festivals](http://www.verbinet.com/events/raclette-cheese-festival) and markets.

Comment: I think this can be it. I've seen raclette only in the first version, but maybe they simply served it differently(in the second version you describe)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it was [raclette](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Raclette)? It is both the kind of cheese and a Swiss dish based on heating a hunk of cheese and scraping off ("racler") the melted part. The more known way to prepare raclette is on a table-top grill which is on the table. Often, other cheeses are used.

[image]

[image]

Sources:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Raclette_with_all_the_trimmings.jpg
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Raclette2.jpg